# Mocha test template with cypress

Tags: mocha.js, cypress

I am writing cypress tests using mocha.
I have 2 applications under the test which are separate apps but kind of have similar functionality that is being tested.
The thing is that I end up with 2 spec files having basically similar logic, the only difference is in the test data provided and maybe some function implementation which is specific to the particular app.

In order to visualize it here are my spec files.
For the sake of an example we have dogs app and cats app where you can buy products for your lovely dogs or cats. This tests the voucher functionality so that you could get some discount on the products.
This is `redeem-voucher-catsapp-spec.ts`

```
import checkoutActions from '../../../support/actions/catsapp/checkout-actions';
import voucherActions from '../../../support/actions/common/voucher-actions';
import {sampleAddressData} from '../../../support/types/checkout-data';
import {localsCatsApp} from '../../../support/types/locals';
import {CheckoutGuestModel, Voucher} from '../../../support/types/types';

context('CatsApp', function() {
    const env = Cypress.env('dataEnv');
    const loc = localsCatsApp.de;

    beforeEach(function() {
        cy.fixture(env + '/users').as('users');
        cy.fixture(env + '/products').as('products');
        cy.fixture(env + '/vouchers').as('vouchers');
    });

    describe('Redeem voucher as a guest user', function() {
        beforeEach(function() {
            this.catsVouchers = this.vouchers.catsapp.voucher;
            this.url = Cypress.env('catsAppBaseurl') + loc.language;
        });

        it('I can redeem valid voucher', function() {
            const voucher: Voucher = {
                code: this.catsVouchers.CHF15.code,
                value: this.catsVouchers.CHF15.value,
                type: this.catsVouchers.CHF15.type,
                threshold: this.catsVouchers.CHF15.threshold
            };
            const checkoutGuestModel: CheckoutGuestModel = {
                url: this.url,
                userAddressData: sampleAddressData,
                product: this.products.catsapp.standardProduct,
                threshold: voucher.threshold
            };

            checkoutActions.landOnCheckoutPageAsGuest(checkoutGuestModel);
            voucherActions.saveCheckoutPricesBeforeApplyingVoucher();

            voucherActions.redeemVoucher(voucher, true, loc);
            voucherActions.verifyVoucherApplied(voucher);

            checkoutActions.finalizeOrder(loc.checkout.orderNowText);
            checkoutActions.verifyCheckoutThankYouPage(loc.checkout.thankYouMessage);
        });
    });
});
```

This is `redeem-voucher-dogsapp-spec.ts`

```
import checkoutActions from '../../../support/actions/DogsApp/checkout-actions';
import voucherActions from '../../../support/actions/common/voucher-actions';
import {sampleAddressData} from '../../../support/types/checkout-data';
import {localsDogsApp} from '../../../support/types/locals';
import {CheckoutGuestModel, Voucher} from '../../../support/types/types';

context('DogsApp', function() {
    const env = Cypress.env('dataEnv');
    const loc = localsDogsApp.de;

    beforeEach(function() {
        cy.fixture(env + '/users').as('users');
        cy.fixture(env + '/products').as('products');
        cy.fixture(env + '/vouchers').as('vouchers');
    });

    describe('Redeem voucher as a guest user', function() {
        beforeEach(function() {
            this.dogsVouchers = this.vouchers.dogsapp.voucher;
            this.url = Cypress.env('DogsAppBaseurl') + loc.language;
        });

        it('I can redeem valid voucher', function() {
            const voucher: Voucher = {
                code: this.dogsVouchers.CHF30.code,
                value: this.dogsVouchers.CHF30.value,
                type: this.dogsVouchers.CHF30.type,
                threshold: this.dogsVouchers.CHF30.threshold
            };
            const checkoutGuestModel: CheckoutGuestModel = {
                url: this.url,
                userAddressData: sampleAddressData,
                product: this.products.dogsapp.standardProduct3,
                threshold: voucher.threshold
            };

            checkoutActions.landOnCheckoutPageAsGuest(checkoutGuestModel);
            voucherActions.saveCheckoutPricesBeforeApplyingVoucher();

            voucherActions.redeemVoucher(voucher, true, loc);
            voucherActions.verifyVoucherApplied(voucher);

            checkoutActions.finalizeOrder(loc.checkout.orderNowText);
            checkoutActions.verifyCheckoutThankYouPage(loc.checkout.thankYouMessage);
        });
    });
});
```

As you can see there is a lot of code duplication going on there.
So I am trying to find a way to write one mocha template spec file which could be parametrized and in which I could pass in test data and function implementation specific to the particular app (like voucher object, url string, voucher fixture file, checkoutActions class specific to each app and so on) and then write 2 spec files which would just "call" my mocha template file with the specific parameters.
Is this possible to do with mocha? And how would you do it?
Please help :)

EDIT:
This is what I have tried inspired by the answers provided example. But the data.ctx seems to be undefined in the mocha `context(`Testing ...`)` function:

```
export interface VoucherTestData {
  ctx: string;
  checkoutActions: CheckoutActions;
}

export function testVoucher(data: VoucherTestData) {

  context(`Testing ${data.ctx}`, function() {

    const env = Cypress.env('dataEnv')
    const loc = data.ctx === 'dog' ? localsDogsApp.de : localsCatsApp.de

    beforeEach(function() {
      cy.fixture(env + '/users').as('users');

      cy.fixture(env + '/products').then(function(products) {
        this.product = this.products[`${data.ctx}app`]
      });     
 
      cy.fixture(env + '/vouchers').then(function(vouchers) {
        this.testVoucher = vouchers[`${data.ctx}app`].voucher
      })

      this.url = Cypress.env(`${data.ctx}AppBaseurl${loc.language}`)
    })
    
    describe('...', function() {

      it('...', function() {

        const voucher: Voucher = {
          code: this.testVoucher.CHF30.code,
          ...
        }

        const checkoutGuestModel: CheckoutGuestModel = {
          ...
          product: this.product.standardProduct3,
        };
```

Comment: Seems like you need to check and correct `data.ctx`

Comment: But the tests says: "Testing dogs"/"Testing cats" while running it, so the string is there. It just becomes undefined in the context and beforeEach area. So I am a bit confused ... ?

Comment: But I can see that data.ctx is defined normally in it blocks. What am I missing here?

Comment: I had a typo in data.ctx as you suggested :/ I was going mad with it. Thank you so much your answer helped me great deal.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've got two ways to apply generic context in javascript

- [template strings](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals)
- [Property accessors by bracket notation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_accessors)

For example,

```js
['dog', 'cat'].forEach(ctx=> {

  context(`Testing ${ctx}`, function() {

    const env = Cypress.env('dataEnv')
    const loc = ctx === 'dog' ? localsDogsApp.de : localsCatsApp.de

    beforeEach(function() {
      cy.fixture(env + '/users').as('users');

      cy.fixture(env + '/products').then(function(products) {
        this.product = this.products[`${ctx}app`]
      });     
 
      cy.fixture(env + '/vouchers').then(function(vouchers) {
        this.testVoucher = vouchers[`${ctx}app`].voucher
      })

      this.url = Cypress.env(`${ctx}AppBaseurl${loc.language}`)
    })
    
    describe('...', function() {

      it('...', function() {

        const voucher: Voucher = {
          code: this.testVoucher.CHF30.code,
          ...
        }

        const checkoutGuestModel: CheckoutGuestModel = {
          ...
          product: this.product.standardProduct3,
        };
```

Comment: This implies that I would have one spec file for both of the apps, right? But I would like to still have separated spec files for each app. Do u have the idea on how to do that?

Comment: I also get this error while trying this out: "Cannot read property 'voucher' of undefined" at the line "this.testVoucher = vouchers[`${data.ctx}`].voucher;"

Comment: it seems to me like ctx is not defined in the beforeEeach? :/

Comment: and ctx is also undefined in context part

Comment: I have updated my answer in order to visualize what I have done with the test where data.ctx parameter remains undefined